# Laravel ORM filter with many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a search by company and/or category.
The output should be listing companies, each & every company output with 1 or more categories.

### Table "companies"

### id     name

1      Company 1
2      Company 2
3      Company 3

### Table "categories"

### id     name

1      Hosting
2      Domain
3      Hardware

### Listing all result

1. Company 1, (categories = Hosting, Domain)
2. Company 2, (Categories = Domain Hardware)
3. Company 3, (Categories = Hardware Hosting)

Now my question is how to build a ORM query so that I can filter categories? Filter by company can be easily to achieve, but I stuck at filter by categories.

Eg output that I wish to achieve.

### Filter Domain, output

1. Company 1, (categories = Hosting, Domain)
2. Company 2, (Categories = Domain Hardware)

Company entry about 20k rows while categories 1k+ rows.

### Failed test

this query taking too long time & eat up processors as well.

```
$companies = Companies
        ::with(['categories'=>function($q)use($category){
            if (isset($category)){
                $q->where('slug','=',$category->slug);
            }
        }])->paginate(20);
```

While this query, only filter the category inside the company modal.

```
$companies = Companies::whereHas('categories',function($q)use($category){
            $q->where('categories.id','=',$category->id);
        })
        ->paginate(20);
```

With 2 modals

**Companies**

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Categories','companies_categories','company_id','category_id');
}
```

**Categories**

```
public function companies(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Companies','companies_categories','category_id','company_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
$companies = Company::has('categories')->get();
```

The result will be the companies that have at least one category. I guess this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since You are using Laravel, this will be easy. In your code all the processing (filtering) is done by the database-server and because of that it takes too much time but there is an another way.

Just fetch all the record using
   `Companies::with('categories')->get();`
This will give you [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-collections) Object which you can process/filter any way you want. you can use `where, orderBy, sortBy` kind of functions which in your above code handled by database-server can now be handle by server plus there are many more functions available.

Comment: tried this method as well. but it taken up resources & take more than 2mins to returns. as the records are 20k companies and 1k categories....

Comment: If those records are not changing then you can use `redis` for caching to store the result of `get` query.

Comment: any examples can refer to achieve it?

Comment: You can check the offical doc of redis for that. Its very easy. check Laravel Redis[https://laravel.com/docs/master/redis] too. I'll try to write an article about this if you find it difficult.